# Libgdx how to set space between the check box and the text label

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I've created a checkbox skin for libgdx Scene2d but the problem that there is no space between my checkbox and the text label , here is my code for the checkbox :

```
final CheckBox vSyncCheckBox = new CheckBox("vSync", skin);
        vSyncCheckBox.setChecked(vSync());
        vSyncCheckBox.getCells().get(0).size(30, 30);
```

and in the table layout i tried to use `spaceRight(10);` but nothing happens :

```
table.add(vSyncCheckBox).top().expandY().spaceRight(10);
```

here is the image on what the checkbox looks like for the moment:

[image]

Like you can see the checkbox and Vsync are stack together any help on how to provide some space between them ?

Comment: Because I'm feeling lazy on the first day of Spring: A space before the 'v' of vSync?

Comment: this do the trick but I'm asking if there is an other why to do this , a method who set the pad between the checkbox and it's label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my similar problem:

```
table.add(yourButton).padLeft(Distance).OTHER_STUFF;
```

Next time please refer to [the Wiki table page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) to solve any problems of or relating table layout

If you have any problems in understanding the concept turn on debugging

```
table.setDebug(true);
```

If your check box and your label is one single item, you can just simply put some space "  vSync" in your declaration of the object instead of "vSync".

Comment: He's not having table issues, he wants to know how to add space between the checkbox and its internal label. And adding a space at the beginning of " vSync" is a hack.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you set space between the check box and the text label.

```
final CheckBox vSyncCheckBox = new CheckBox("vSync", skin);
vSyncCheckBox.getLabelCell().padLeft(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the whole code of that table? It might be not working because of other settings made to the table.

Also, it can be helpful to activate debug mode by using

```
table.setDebug(true); // turn on all debug lines (table, cell, and widget)
```

Source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#debugging